# What might cause "System.SecurityException: Required permissions are not enabled."

Tags: apex, permissions, execute-anonymous

I'm running an apex method anonymously using SoqlXplorer:

```
AccountClass.recalcAccount(accountId);
```

I'm greeted with this error in the response:

```
FATAL_ERROR|System.SecurityException: Required permissions are not enabled.
```

I'm looking at the dependency information for the AccountClass class, and my profile has access to all of the features, objects (full CRUD), and other apex classes.

What else might cause this error?

Comment: Do you get the same error when using Developer Console or Workbench?

Comment: What occured immediately before the FATAL_ERROR in the Debug log? Try setting the logging levels to the finest levels to see what was going on.

Comment: crop1645 -- yes.
Daniel Ballinger -- Turned debugging to FINEST, and there's no additional information displayed other than some HEAP_ALLOCATEs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was experiencing this error; it was due to my profile not having "author apex" privilege enabled.

- While logged into your Salesforce instance, click your name at top right.
- Choose "setup" in the dropdown menu.
- In the search box, enter your username or email address.
- Choose the record that corresponds to your user record
- Click into your profile
- Click edit
- use browser search (control-F on windows or linux, or command-F on OS X) to find "author apex" permission
- Check the box to enable "author apex" permission
- Save

This should resolve the error.

Comment: Please show the steps to enable the 'Author Apex' privilege to give a more complete answer - see [answer]

Comment: Edited response, above.

Comment: Was not the case for me.  I was system admin.  Looks like a good answer though, and no way to know what the issue actually was with this org from 2 years ago.  I'll mark it accepted.